# access to pdf file from extjs

Tags: pdf, extjs4

I work with Ext JS 4.

I have generated a PDF (test.pdf) using Java and I make this PDF under WebContent using this code.

```
net.sf.jasperreports.engine.JasperExportManager.exportReportToPdfFile(
    jasperPrint,
    "D:/workSpace/Urbanisme/WebContent/theme/" + outputFileName);
```

Now I want to display this PDF in a panel.

```
new Ext.Window({
    title:  "print",
    width:  640,
    height: 480,
    layout: 'fit',
    items:  [{
        xtype: "component",
        autoEl: {
            tag: "iframe",
            src: '/urbanisme/theme/test.pdf'
        }
    }]
}).show();
```

But I have this error:

**etat http 404 -/urbanisme/theme/test.pdf**

I solve this error by refreshing my project, specifically the file **theme**, and after refresh test.pdf will be displayed in my project.

I want to know how can I refresh my project after I generate a PDF, or if I make the generated PDF in `C:` I want to know how can I access to `C:` from Ext JS 4.

I try without success with

```
new Ext.Window({
    title:  "print",
    width:  640,
    height: 480,
    layout: 'fit',
    items:  [{
        xtype: "component",
        autoEl: {
            tag: "iframe",
            src: 'C://test.pdf'
        }
    }]
}).show();
```

Comment: You cannot. You need backend service for that. for example with php

Comment: thank you for your response,  but I want to know how can i open a pdf file from disc, as I already said I try with ; src: 'C://test.pdf'     src: 'C:\\test.pdf'

Answer (score 0):

In order to reference a file on your local file system, you need to use the [File URI Scheme](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/File_URI_scheme). The basic format is `file://host/path` but in the general case, you'll use `file:///C:/path/to/file`. Three slashes, and slashes instead of backslashes in the file path.

```
xtype:  'component',
autoEl: {
    tag: 'iframe',
    src: 'file:///C:/test.pdf'
}
```